# offcanvas lateral sin ocultar contenido de la pagina

Tags: bootstrap

estoy intentando hacer un offcanvas sin ocultar el contenido de la pagina, simplemente que todo el contenido se desplace, estoy haciendo con bootstrap

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasScrolling" aria-controls="offcanvasScrolling">Enable body scrolling</button>

<div class="offcanvas offcanvas-start" data-bs-scroll="true" data-bs-backdrop="false" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasScrolling" aria-labelledby="offcanvasScrollingLabel">
  <div class="offcanvas-header">
    <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasScrollingLabel">Offcanvas with body scrolling</h5>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="offcanvas-body">
    <p>Try scrolling the rest of the page to see this option in action.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Creo que no tiene mucho sentido utilizar el componente offcanvas, ya que este es un overlay similar a un modal, por lo tanto no "empuja" el contenido. Para eso Bootstrap ya tiene un elemento "collapse", que podrías aplicar perfectamente a un sidebar vertical por ejemplo. Te comparto un snippet que podría servirte de guía: 
https://www.codeply.com/p/NbvlptiZCf